# Balls having finite measure

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

What conditions on a measure space with a metric guarantee that all balls will have finite measure? Will it be true if the measure is regular?

Comment: Are you looking for sufficient conditions? How tight do hyou want the condition to be? The trivial one is $\mu(X)<\infty$!

Comment: I am specifically thinking if regularity will be a sufficient condition or not.

Comment: Do you mean inner regularity or outer regularity or both?

Comment: What about $\sigma$-finiteness? Its weaker than $\mu(X)< \infty$

Comment: I meant both inner and outer regularity. How does $\sigma$-finiteness imply the that all balls have finite measure?

Answer (score 1):

Regularity is certainly not enough. For example the measure with density
$$ \frac{1}{x} dx$$
on the half line $(0,\infty)$ (with the usual metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}$) does not have the property that all balls have finite measure. On the other hand, it is regular (assuming you mean by regularity the same thing that [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure) does) and $\sigma$-finite.

I never know how to answer these questions that go "what condition implies the condition I want" -- why not just say the property you need and go from there? But if you insist on a commonly used assumption that implies that all balls have finite measure, then the "doubling" property of a measure (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space ) usually by fiat includes the property you want.